Is the difference-in-difference valid in this case?
I am assessing a report which assess the impact of DBT's export promotion activities in the UK on firm-level outcomes using a combination of propensity score matching and difference-in-differences.
There are firms which are treated only once in 2014 while others are treated multiple times in 2014. At the same time, there are firms that are treated for multiple years as well. In such a case, is it possible at all to estimate any causal impact of the treatment? Or is the DiD completely invalid?

Welcome to the site! Please add some more detail about your data, possibly with some example data as it will be easier to provide an answer.
